# Equivalent of two one-sided t-tests for binomial test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, binomial-distribution

I want to verify that the phenomenon I am observing is generated by a Binomial distribution with $p \approx 0.5$. The normal Binomial test verifies the opposite: a small p-value gives me confidence that the parameter p is NOT 0.5.

I thought I could verify that $0.5-\delta < p < 0.5+\delta$ using the trick of the "two one-sided t-tests", which tests that the mean of a process is within an interval $[l_1,l_2]$ by testing that it is not smaller than $l_1$ and that it is not larger than $l_2$.

My questions then are:

1. Is my approach sensible?
2. How do I aggregate the two p-values to obtain an overall p-value? I see [statsmodels's ttost_ind](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.weightstats.ttost_ind.html) takes the maximum of the two p-values: can I do the same?
3. What works can I cite to back the correctness of this method if I publish my research?

Bonus question: Can you give me the exact lines to implement this using [SciPy's scipy.stats.binom_test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binom_test.html)?

Comment: You can't verify it *is* $0.5$, only that it's "equivalent" (which loosely speaking means that it's not too far from $0.5$).

Comment: Can I use the test mentioned to "verify" that p is within a given interval? (edited the question for precision)

Comment: you could take a look at this: http://www.astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/stats/html/binom.test.html

Comment: @fcop That is the normal Binomial test, it does not compute what I want.

Comment: I might be missing something, but how about a confidence interval about the proportion?  If it includes 0.5, it gives no evidence that the proportion isn't 0.5.

Comment: @tam yes, in the intended sense; that's what I was saying.

Comment: statsmodels has a proportion section with http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.proportion.binom_tost.html http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.proportion.proportions_ztost.html

Comment: There are several very interesting articles about "shifting the burden of proof" by using equivalence (TOST) tests, but I don't have the references anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is about as sensible as doing the same with another statistical distribution. There are some problems that need to be addressed.

Regarding p-values, if you allocate half of your $\alpha$ level to each one sided test you should be on the safe side. That's a Bonferroni correction for multiple testing. Other methods like a Holm correction are less conservative, have more statistical power. It is a little more tedious to implement but should be possible as well.

Your test will also be more conservative than the $\alpha$ level indicates since the binomial distribution is discrete. Suppose you allocate 2.5% $\alpha$ per one sided test. It may be that the largest p-value attainable with your binomial distribution that lies beneath 2.5% is infact considerably lower than 2.5%, perhaps 1.8%. In this case you would be testing at a more stringent significance level than your nominal $\alpha$ suggests. This effect is larger with smaller sample sizes since then the jumps are bigger

The most important problem is the $\delta$ term that you need to use. It is not possible to do equivalence testing without such a term, but you need to motivate it well. This term gives you a researcher degree of freedom that will make the reviewer suspicious. To be frank, you could always post-hoc increase $\delta$ so that the two one sided null hypothese get rejected and you prove your equivalence. It would be very difficult for the reviewer to know if you fixed $\delta$ before seeing the data, hence the suspicion. You need to determine your $\delta$ in a principled way by stating that an effect of $\delta$ or more would start being practically relevant (as opposed to statistically significant) and ideally have a citation for that value.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Could you elaborate on why it is necessary to set a $\delta$ in advance as opposed to report the $\delta$ I found to show significance? Isn't the latter also informative?

Comment: Also, it seems to me that the Bonferroni correction is used when I am interested in finding *any* significance among many tests, while in my case I want to verify that *all* my tests are significant. Is this correct?

Comment: Finally, just to understand, why the TOST just takes the maximum p-value while in my case it is necessary to apply corrections?

Comment: Having to rely on a delta at all is problematic enough. If you cannot show that you chose it in a principled way and independent of the data, the assumption will be that you cranked it up just enough to make your findings statistically significant. The Bonferroni correction corrects for multiple testing, it doesn't tell you what to do with those multiple tests. In your case, you need both to be significant after correction so you look at both. Regarding only the max, if you look only at the max and verify its under half of alpha, than that's just a weird way of saying you look at both.

Comment: Thanks! More on $\delta$ though: I still do not understand what is the problem in looking for the most strict $\delta$ that passes the test. Isn't that equally informative to the reader, if I state that how found it?

Comment: This just in: women are as heavy as men on average! Footnote in small print: TOST procedure with a delta of 15kg as decided by the statistician, but the p-value is significant!!! In this example, the scale in it is intuitive and the reader would detect the scam. In most scientific papers however, the scale is much less intuitive. The reader couldn't know if your delta is adequate as a minimum relevant difference or if you cranked it up.

Comment: I see, your example is clear. Would it be more fair to state something like "Assuming a Binomial distribution as a model, we have >95% confidence that the parameter $p$ lies withing the interval $[0.4,0.6]$, but we could not conclude it lies within $[0.45,0.55]$" (not in small print!)? Or equivalently just reporting the $p$-values for different $\delta$s? In other words, I cannot see the advantage of pre-determining a value as opposed to finding more "p-value" data points to "draw" its curve depending on $\delta$.

Comment: Yes much better. The alternative would be to show that 55 to 45 chances can practically still be considered equal in your application scenario. If you can show that, you can use delta as 0.05. But I would prefer the confidence interval

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64928/discussion-between-tamzord-and-user7019377).

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is, you are trying to use hypothesis testing for something it can't really do, which is claiming that a certain (even approximate) value GAVE rise to something you observed.

What in my opinion would work as a heuristic is that you take your lower ($0.5 - \delta$) and upper bound($0.5 + \delta$) and calculate the probabilities of observing the result that you have - for the lower bound you could do a right-tailed test, for the upper bound you could take a left-tailed test.

Scipy should be (but I'm not 100% about that, I don't use SciPy so can't test):

scipy.stats.binom.pdf(your_test_result, n, 1/2 - delta) * 2

(1 - scipy.stats.binom.pdf(your_test_result, n, 1/2 + delta)) * 2

This would give you two probabilities that would upper bound the probability of your observation for all "truthes" outside of your specified range (edit: I'm assuming here that your observation is within your specified range). But I would like to stress that this would not allow you to infer a probability for the truth being in your specified interval, since ultimately this requires a model/assumption on the true value of p.

To really answer a question like this, you would need Bayesian Methods (which gives you ways to model the prior distribution of p you need to actually quantify interval probabilities) - If it's important that you get this right, maybe switching to Bayesian is the way? In that case you might search for "Bayesian credible intervals"

Comment: I seem to understand that your argument could be applied to the case of TOST as well. From that, I infer that TOST is also not a "good" method to verify the mean lies within an interval. However, TOST is part of SciPy, so I cannot help but think it has some theoretical backing. Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: I wasn't familiar with TOST, but having had a quick look at it, it seems to fall into the category of "it makes sense" rather than "it's perfectly aligned with hypothesis testing". Statistical hypothesis testing doesn't really allow you to infer anything about the true value, generally, but I believe many tests have been thought up trying to do that regardless. It's the old question of "how many different things do I have to try to reject the null until I can have some certainty that the null is true" - But as I said, I'm not very familiar with the test or it's theoretical foundation